# Smart way to update debian in wordpress docker compose container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, debian

Is there a smart way to update && upgrade Debian in a Wordpress docker container without starting a shell in the container and run the update command manually?

I use docker-compose as manager.

Comment: What would be the point of doing so ?

Comment: To install the latest security update for the underlying OS, which is in case of the Wordpress Container, Debian.

Comment: Normal procedure is to rebuild your application's image with a newer version of the base OS and dependencies, then delete and recreate the container using the newer image.

Answer (score -1):

You could override the entrypoint / command replacing it by you update commande and the original entrypoint / command.
Alternatively you could override the [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/193647657b9c00b68b63ba9ecf306c915764f8f5/docker-entrypoint.sh) used by the wordpress image